# Fill gaps between lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, line, gap

I have a line layer in which the lines have several gaps.

[image]

How can I quickly close the gaps in QGIS 3.4?

Is there a tool or plugin available I haven't found yet?

Comment: Actually, this is _by far_ not as trivial as you may think. Using your example, imagine a third line with a valid end point (meaning there _should_ be a gap, for reasons) somewhere near one of those two you have drawn; how would you make any algorithm decide which gap to close? Do you have any common identifier for lines that should get connected? E.g. a road name, based on which a set of vertices can be connected to a single line? Or are there any attribute sequences used to determine line order? Are all lines digitized in a consistent direction?

Comment: As geozelot notes this is not trivial. I did it many years ago in MapBasic on a sewer network using buffers on line endpoints looking for other lines startpoint within the buffer and also checking attributes identifying a sewer line like material and dimension. Got like a 90% match and the sewer company was happy. Don't know the Join multiple lines plugin, but is seems like a manual process selecting first what to be joined.

Answer (score 8):

The ***Join multiple lines*** plugin seems to do this:

> After selecting multiple features of a line layer, this plugin can
>   merge them into one feature with a continuous line. The plugin will
>   automatically put the selected lines in a geographically logical order
>   and direction. If the end points of two lines do not match exactly, a
>   line segment between both points is added to make the end result a
>   single, continuous line. The attributes of the new line will be those
>   of one of the selected features, but one cannot predict which one.

Comment: After desperate trying different way to close gaps between only about six parts of a bike trail this was my rescue! The answer should much more appreciated!